# Strange Python syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm creating a program that looks like it's compiling something (it isn't) and I'm getting a strange `invalid syntax` error. I have the following code:

```
import random
from time import sleep
files = ["main.cpp", "include.h", "connect.c", "mainProgram.java", "start.py", "lfm.java"]
verbs =  ["Compiling ", "Checking ", "Debugging ", "Building "]
errors = ["stack_overflow", "divide_by_zero", "str_int_error", "syntax_error", "math_error"]
lineNums = ["4", "24", "13", "73", "48", "33", "172", "129", "145", "206"]
sleepFor = ["1", "3", "12", "15", "30", "43", "62"]
error = "Error: "
onLine = " on line "
minute = " (This may take a minute...)"

def random():
    num = random.randint(0, 10)
    return num

while True:
    num = random()
    if (num > 7):
        print(random.choice(verbs) + random.choice(files) + minute)
        sleep(random.choice(sleepFor))
    elif (num == 0):    
        print(error + random.choice(errors) + onLine + random.choice(lineNums)
        sleep(random.choice(sleepFor))
    else:
        print(random.choice(verbs) + random.choice(files))
        sleep(random.choice(sleepFor))
```

And for some reason, it's giving me an error at the following part of the code (where I called the `sleep` function)

```
elif (num == 0):    
        print(error + random.choice(errors) + onLine + random.choice(lineNums)
        sleep(random.choice(sleepFor))
```

I haven't seen any syntax errors in my code. Is something wrong with the indentation? I've indented it right, so I don't think so.

Comment: Where's the closing `)` for `print()`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that's the strange syntax error  :p

Comment: @AshwiniChaudray It works now, thanks! Sometimes I think that Python2 was better than Python3 because sometimes I get confused by the parentheses.

Comment: You should not name a function after a module you are importing. Also, you only call it once in your program. Why not just do num = random.randint(0, 10) ?

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the version of python (or python in general), any open parenthesis has to be closed.

Comment: @Programmer I though I would be using the function more than one time but seems I was mistaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is missing a closing parenthesis:

```
print(error + random.choice(errors) + onLin+random.choice(lineNums)
```

Correct it to

```
print(error + random.choice(errors) + onLin+random.choice(lineNums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the line;

```
print(error + random.choice(errors) + onLin+random.choice(lineNums)
```

I suggest that you use an editor that has syntax highlighting, that would have made this apparent rather fast ;)

I assume that you meant the following:

```
print(error + random.choice(errors) + onLin+random.choice(lineNums))
```

Comment: I use Sublime Text 2, which has syntax highlighting.

Comment: What does that editor 'highlight' when you have the first parenthesis selected on the respective line?

Answer (score 0):

```
to_test=open("my_program.py")
program=to_test.read()

print(program.count("("))
print(program.count(")"))
```

21

20